# How many people can watch and post questions on Google direct Hangout?

Tags: google-hangouts

I read everywhere Google Hangout can accept 10 people. **But how many people can watch** and post questions on the application "Questions & answers" include in the Hangout direct?

I can't believe only 10 people can watch the direct hangout and post questions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering it late,
The normal hangout can only be seen by maximum upto 10 peoples. So to make an hangouts accessible to more number of peoples :-

- **Set hangout type as hangout on air** - Set hangout type as hangout on air and moderator have to broadcast to make the video accessible to outsiders other than the hangout participants(those who have actually joined the hangout).
- **Broadcast the hangout on air** - soon after the hangout is broadcasted( a live youtube video streaming of the hangout is started on youtube) you can get the liveyoutubeid of the broadcast video and display it on your application.

So thats all you need to do to make the hangout accessible to more number of peoples, and to coming to your second question about adding a feature so that the viewers can interacts with the participants. You can use services like pusher or slanger to communicate the messages(questions and answers) in realtime between the hangout app and the application.